# Trouble with .remove() when theres a hash in the url

Tags: jquery

I have a simple animation that plays on my homepage. It works with an empty div with an animated height/margin. This works great, but I'd like to be able to link to specific anchors without the animation.

So, my solution is to simply remove that empty div (class="pushtocenter" when there is a hash in the URL.

```
(window.location.hash) && $(".pushtocenter").remove();
```

However, the div stays put. The `(window.location.hash) &&` works, because I've checked it using `console.log`, but for some reason `.remove()` just isn't doing anything.

At first, I thought it was because the div was inserted via a php include, necessitating .on(), but I simply moved it out of the include, so it's not that. :(

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you verify that the ".remove()" method is not being called BEFORE the .pushcenter div is rendered.. Maybe you try to remove before its in the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if((window.location.hash)){
    $(".pushtocenter").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

and to make sure its loaded when called.

Adding to what Hiral suggests.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    if((window.location.hash)){
       $(".pushtocenter").remove();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`&& $(".pushtocenter").remove();` is an absolutely worthless test . jQuery methods that aren't being used as getters  all return `this` in order to be chain able. You are making an incorrect assumption that `remove()` will return a boolean, which it does not.

It can never be false since it returns an object.